# How to add transparent browser windows for UX/UI wireframes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, mockup

I'm sure there's some tools available. Other than hand designing browser windows, other programs and export transparent wireframes? Has anyone made browser windows themselves with illustrator or Photoshop? If so, did you follow a strict workflow or abstract Windows from Balsamiq?

[image: Transparant browser window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Illustrator for wire framing. It seems to provide more versatility for me. I don't use any online services although I have looked into a few of them. While they can be handy to share brainstorming ideas, they can be equally hindering in the completions of the framing stage (allowing too many to continually adjust). And, I own Illustrator, I've never seen a reason to pay additional fees for such a simple thing as wireframing.

And I've created my own browser frames in Illustrator which are an amalgamation of common aspects between all the browsers. These can easily be pasted into Photoshop as smart objects should the need arise.

Comment: I'm not adept in Illustrator. Any resources that you would be willing to share?

Comment: @Charles There really aren't any direct resources. Illustrator construction merely takes some rectangles and coloring. Nothing overly complex.